# Storing Time Values and Comparing Them

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, time, nsdate

I am trying to have points in time and then compare them. I have figured out how to compare them, but I am trying to create `NSDate` objects to represent times of day, and it is causing some trouble. I used `NSDateFromComponents` and used the `setHour:` and `setMinute:` functions, but it does not successfully modify the object. It also needs to automatically set the other components of the date to the current time and date.

COMPARING OBJECTS:

```
static bool DateIsBetween(NSDate *beginDate, NSDate *date, NSDate *endDate) {
    return [date timeIntervalSince1970] > [beginDate timeIntervalSince1970] && [date    timeIntervalSince1970] < [endDate timeIntervalSince1970];
}
```

CREATING DATE OBJECTS:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:todayDate];

NSDateComponents *genericTimeComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

[genericTimeComponents setHour:5];
[genericTimeComponents setMinute:0];
[genericTimeComponents setDay:weekdayComponents.day];
[genericTimeComponents setYear:weekdayComponents.year];
[genericTimeComponents setMonth:weekdayComponents.month];


NSDateComponents *secondComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[secondComps setHour:7];
[secondComps setMinute:0];
[secondComps setDay:weekdayComponents.day];
[secondComps setYear:weekdayComponents.year];
[secondComps setEra:weekdayComponents.era];
[secondComps setMonth:weekdayComponents.month];
```

Comment: paste your code here. That'll help us in pinpointing the source of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use parentheses in your date compare function (for the sake of clarity only; logically, it should work just fine):

```
 static bool DateIsBetween(NSDate *beginDate, NSDate *date, NSDate *endDate) {
    return (([date timeIntervalSince1970] > [beginDate timeIntervalSince1970]) && ([date    timeIntervalSince1970] < [endDate timeIntervalSince1970]));
}
```

For such cases, it's a good idea to create a category for NSDate class and write an objective-c method.

For the rest, I tried the following code and it worked for me:

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDateComponents *genericTimeComponents = [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSEraCalendarUnit)
                                                      fromDate:now];

[genericTimeComponents setHour:5];
[genericTimeComponents setMinute:0];

//  Quick Check 
NSLog(@"GTC=%@", genericTimeComponents);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making a C function. Indeed, making it a method in a category has the risk that Apple will create (or already privately have) a method of the same name, in which case any differences between how your method behaves and how Apple's method behaves will cause problems.

Comment: That's why when creating methods in a category, always prefix the method namse with with your orgs initials. Extending a class can result in a very readable and easy to use code. Never implied that there's anything "wrong" with writing a C function, it's just a matter of style and consistency. At the very least, I wanted the OP to be aware of the option.